# kernel IRQ domain list

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, irq, soc

I'm developping a simple GPIO driver for a SoC running linux (newbie's level),
I am facing problem because IRQ numbers are different from those in datasheets.

I've learned that effective IRQ manager may create IRQ domains.
However  the

unsigned int irq_find_mapping(struct irq_domain *domain, irq_hw_number_t hwirq) needs a domain structure.
How can I list the available domain for my plateform.
Thank you.

here are some files' content

file: irq_domain_mapping 
    `name       mapped linear-max direct-max devtree_node
    gpio-dwapb 29     29         0          /soc/gpio@ff709000/gpio-controller 
    ...
    99 0x00019 none` 
 
file : /proc/interrupts 
    `99 ... 25 edge gpiolib`   
however DTS file maps the interruption at 197 with dwapb manager  
 
    `interrupts = <0x00000000 0x000000a5 0x00000004>`

Comment: `cat /sys/kernel/debug/irq_domain_mapping`. Be sure you have *CONFIG_IRQ_DOMAIN_DEBUG=y* in the kernel configuration.

Comment: I've edited my question,  the interruption is mapped to 197 in DTS file but is set to 99 in linux

Comment: It would be better if you gather all 3 files (/proc/interrupts, irq_domain_mapping and DTS with code in question) on some internet share (pastebin like) w/ **full** contents.

Answer (score 0):

There are many things to consider:

1. /proc/interrupts will give IRQ number you can use that directly.
2. BSP documentation mentions IRQ assigned/used by drivers.
3. See kernel code /arch/arm/your-platform files, you will see IRQ Numbers assigned.
4. Device tree file is the best option for identifying the IRQ number.

Comment: thank you for your support, I'll check the third suggestion because the others does not meet my needs

Comment: See my comment to OP.